# JQUERY: script inside my dialog keeps looping

Tags: jquery

I am having a strange issue. I have a dialog which has an Add button, and after entering text, another add button. But suppose I enter a second comment, it goes through the loop twice, and similarly a third, it loops thrice. But i can see where the error is.Please can you guide me?

```
 $("#show").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 500,
                    height: 650,
                    title: "Job Reference " + jobid,
                    modal: true,
                    show: 'fold',
                    buttons: {
                        "Add Comment": function () {
                            $("#AddCommentDialog").dialog({
                                resizable: false,
                                width: 500,
                                height: 200,
                                title: "Add Comment",
                                modal: true,
                                buttons: {
                                    "Add": function () {
                                        var text = $("#JobCommenttext").val();
                                        if (text.length > 0) {
                                            $("#User-Login").dialog();
                                            $("#verify").click(function () {
                                                var username = $("#username").val();
                                                var password = $("#password").val();
                                                if (username == '' || password == '') {
                                                    alert("Please fill all fields");
                                                } else {
                                                    verifyUser(username, password);
                                                    if (verifyUser) {
                                                        UpdateComments(jobid, text, username);
                                                        $("#JobCommenttext").val('');
                                                        $("#username").val('');
                                                        $("#password").val('');
                                                        $("#User-Login").dialog("close");
                                                        $("#show").dialog("close");
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            })
```

Comment: `$("#verify").click(function ()` is *inside* the button click event.  So each time you click `Add` you get another event on `#verify`.  Move that part outside.

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m, can you tell me where I need to move it? I am trying to move it out of the Add, but then losing my text and job id values. But this is a good start. Thank You

Comment: Yes, that would be the problem (partly why I only commented, not answered).  You'd have to store them somewhere else (eg as `data-jobid=` or `$("#verify").data("jobid", jobid)`) and then read them back when they're used.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `.one` or `.on`/`.off` instead of `.click`, eg `$("#verify").off("click").on("click", function() ....` which will ensure your verify button only ever has one event handler.

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m, I used .one and it solved my issue. Thank You so much. I cant mark this as an answer but appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using .one to the click event. This prevented the function from running twice. 
.one ensures that the event runs only once so this prevented the looping. Thanks to @freedomn-m